# Ionic native Printer plugin not working. Does printer plugin need special initialization step?

Tags: cordova, plugins, printing

I have reviewed the same problem someone else posted before ([Ionic native Printer plugin not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43676697/ionic-native-printer-plugin-not-working)), but I already did everything mentioned there and it is still not working. It always say the picking/print is not available on the device.

```
this.printer.pick().then(function() {
    alert("Picking printer done successfully !");
}, function() {
    alert('Error : picking printer unavailable on your device ');
});

this.printer.isAvailable().then(function() {
    this.printer.print(page, options).then(function() {
        alert("printing done successfully !");
    }, function() {
        alert("Error while printing !");
    });
}, function() {
    alert('Error : printing is unavailable on your device ');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using "**function()**" inside another function. Try this

```
this.printer.pick().then(pickSuccess => {
    alert("Picking printer done successfully !");
}, pickError => {
    alert('Error : picking printer unavailable on your device ');
});

this.printer.isAvailable().then(isAvailableSuccess => {
    this.printer.print(page, options).then(printSuccess => {
        alert("printing done successfully !");
    }, printError => {
        alert("Error while printing !");
    });
}, isAvailableError => {
    alert('Error : printing is unavailable on your device ');
});
```