# I have problem with ionic native plugin for printing ionic 4

Tags: ionic-framework, printing, native, ionic-native

I have a problem with this code when I run in the android device also ios I have the same problem

```
TypeError: Printer.getPlugin(...).check is not a function
    at vendor.js:79303
    at vendor.js:78443
    at new ZoneAwarePromise (polyfills.js:3272)
    at tryNativePromise (vendor.js:78442)
    at getPromise (vendor.js:78463)
    at vendor.js:79301
    at Printer.push../node_modules/@ionic-native/printer/ngx/index.js.Printer.check (vendor.js:79308)
    at Printer.push../node_modules/@ionic-native/printer/ngx/index.js.Printer.isAvailable (vendor.js:79294)
    at SaleInfoPage.push../src/app/paenter code herege/sale-info/sale-info.page.ts.SaleInfoPage.print (main.js:1037)
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (SaleInfoPage.html:54)
```

ionic info

Ionic:

Ionic CLI                     : 5.2.1 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.6.0
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.13.9
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 7.3.9
   @angular/cli                  : 7.3.9
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 1.5.1

Cordova:

Cordova CLI       : 8.0.0
   Cordova Platforms : android 8.0.0, ios 4.5.5
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.1, (and 9 other plugins)

Utility:

cordova-res : 0.5.0 (update available: 0.5.2)
   native-run  : 0.2.6 (update available: 0.2.7)

System:

Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (/Users/shahab/Library/Android/sdk/)
   ios-deploy        : 2.0.0
   NodeJS            : v8.11.3 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm               : 5.6.0
   OS                : macOS Mojave
   Xcode             : Xcode 10.2.1 Build version 10E

code in function

```
print()
  {
    this.printer.isAvailable().then(function(){
      this.printer.print("https://www.techiediaries.com").then(function(){
            alert("printing done successfully !");
          },function(){
            alert("Error while printing !");
          });
    }, function(e){
        console.log(e);
        alert('Error : printing is unavailable on your device ');
    });
  }
```

Comment: share your code. and Ionic info

Comment: i added please see it

Comment: Try to remove platform and add again.

Comment: I tried many time

Comment: but have same problem

Comment: have you added your plugin in your `app.module.ts` file?

Comment: providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy },
    NativeStorage,
    CallNumber,
    Printer    
  ],

Comment: I added to file

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43680418/5909026

Comment: My friend, I have the same problem also,
all native plugin  working just printing not work

Comment: let me know your plugin Version

Comment: "@ionic-native/printer": "^5.9.0",
    "cordova-plugin-printer": "^0.8.0",

Comment: try to downgrade cordova-plugin-printer to 0.7.4

Comment: No matching version found for cordova-plugin-printer@0.7.4
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.

Comment: @Najamussaqib I downgrade to 0.7.3 I have same problem

Comment: @Najamussaqib please help me i don't have time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by installing this plugin with the same library 
[isiigoteam/cordova-plugin-printer](https://github.com/isiigoteam/cordova-plugin-printer#readme)