# cordova-plugin-printer @ionic-native/printer ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError

Tags: cordova, printing, ionic4, ionic-native

I need to print html content from android app using ionic framework(v4). I find the cordova-plugin-printer in the oficial docs, but i can' t make it works.
According to [docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/printer), you only have to install the plugin and the wrapper later.

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-printer
npm install @ionic-native/printer
```

Then when inject the Printer object i get NullInjector error

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[TabComprobantePage -> Printer]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[TabComprobantePage -> Printer]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for Printer!
NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[TabComprobantePage -> Printer]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[TabComprobantePage -> Printer]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for Printer!
    at NullInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NullInjector.get (core.js:725)
    at resolveToken (core.js:11917)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:11861)
    at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (core.js:11763)
    at resolveToken (core.js:11917)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:11861)
    at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (core.js:11763)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:20233)
    at NgModuleRef_.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgModuleRef_.get (core.js:20904)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:20233)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:852)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:809)
    at zone.js:913
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:26246)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:422)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:195)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:601)
```

I tried adding Printer to providers/imports with no success. Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Has you try this yet? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43676697/ionic-native-printer-plugin-not-working

Comment: Or Maybe you need to declare the printer in the current page module

Comment: Yes @SnowBases. I tried already, with no results. Also tried to add Printer as provider in both modules, app-module and in the module of the current component. Thanks for answer

Answer (score 5):

I tried now and it is work smoothly if you add printer plugin into my App.Module.ts as a provider it works.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';
import { Printer } from '@ionic-native/printer/ngx';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    Printer,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Thanks Emre. I had already tried adding it in the app.module. I made it work with the plugin https://github.com/isiigoteam/cordova-plugin-printer.